# Node.js: Express.js set keep-alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the correct way for set [keep alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) in express.js web server?

I have found some examples..

**Example n. 1**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5001);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
});
```

**Example n. 2**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5001);
server.keepAliveTimeout = 30 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `server.headersTimeout` with a value higher than `server.keepAliveTimeout`. ([check this solution for a similar issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363#issuecomment-487507422) and [this page](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2019/04/25/keep-alive-timeout/) out)

example code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5001);
server.keepAliveTimeout = 30 * 1000;
server.headersTimeout = 35 * 1000;
```

Comment: As of node version 12.19.0 there is no longer any need to set headersTimeout larger than keepAliveTimeout. [https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363#issuecomment-705085158)